# What method(s) answer question 'should X be a category'?

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning

To some degree my problem may be lacking terminology to ask the question well.

Form of a problem I'm looking at is as follows: some number of subjects answered (luckily in a binary way, that is: 'yes', 'no', 'missing') some number of questions. What would be a way to tell if those subjects can be categorized in any/a way?

Specific example would be people rating pieces of art and there being people who 'like colour red'.

I'm aware that answers to those types of questions tend to be a shifting scale of trade-offs, since it is effectively inventing a bit of science. That also gives me some ideas how to approach this - mainly removing questions from the dataset randomly, doing any form of clustering and seeing how well existing clusters predict response to the missing question.

Still, I'm looking for tooling, name for the problem I'm looking at etc. that I could learn more about to make some better choices. It seems like some type of unsupervised learning, but what are more specific descriptions/names I could use to learn more here?

Comment: Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_analysis.

Comment: From what I can tell, it's focused on visualization and forces two dimensions, both of which I don't really need. I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: Hi! Have you searched the website? What you're looking for is certainly related to clustering of categorical data: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=clustering+categorical . By the way, multiple correspondence analysis does not force two dimensions, and offers much more output than just a plot.

Comment: I did! I'm trying to ask how I can rate the clustering I get - is there some additional term I should add to search? Either different from the predictive power measure I came up with or formalizing it further? I know to an extend it's 'does it work?' kind of problem, but surely there's some whole class of formalizations I don't know how to find.


I'll look further into CA, it was my first impression from wiki summary, thanks.

Comment: My bad! I interpreted your question as "how to cluster observations having categorical variables?", and not "how to rate the clustering result I got?". Searching for "clustering validation" should be helpful (you may even drop the term "categorical"), even though I haven't checked if there are a lot of questions/answers about it around here.